# Python while wait 100 seconds and return True or False

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, while-loop

I have python script below, which checks whether ping is success, If it success within 100 Seconds it will return True. If ping is failed it should return False but it is not returning False and when ping is success it is returning True.

Can anyone fix below code why it is not return False

Code:

```
def ping(self,hostname):
        time_check = datetime.now()
        data = ""
        while not "Success" in data:
            time.sleep(1)
            data = self.pingCheck("ping 10.10.10.1 count 5")
            if (datetime.now()-time_check).seconds > 100:
                return False
        return True
```

Comment: Check `.total_seconds` instead of `.seconds`. Very different meaning

Comment: seems working to me. Are you sure that `self.pingCheck("ping 10.10.10.1 count 5")` is not returning something that contains `"Success"`?

Comment: can you post the code for pingCheck too?

Comment: sorry everyone, This is  my mistake pingCheck is has one more timer and it does sys.exit()..Can i delete this post

Comment: You really should. Off screen errors like that aren't really useful to future readers.

Answer (score -1):

The code below will work for you:

```
import time

def ping(self, hostname, try_for=100):
    t_end = time.time() + try_for
    is_succeed = False
    while time.time() < t_end or is_succeed:
        time.sleep(1)
        data = self.pingCheck("ping 10.10.10.1 count 5")
        is_succeed = "Success" in data
    return is_succeed
```

I've defined wait time as parameter called `try_for`, which default value is set to `100`, but you can pass any other amount of seconds which you want spend waiting for host availability.

Comment: @Mad Physicist I see your point, just considered that another way of doing that may be cleaner.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with the way you structured your code. It's just that SO is a Q&A site that is meant to help as many as people as possible experiencing similar problems. Saying "this will work" and dumping some code without explanation doesn't really achieve that goal. Try to explain the non-obvious. Why did OP's code not work? Why is yours any better?